# Celery result disabled?

Tags: celery, python-3.4

I am playing with demo cases with celery tutorial. However, the results were shown disabled when I start the task app. as below. Any idea?

```
celery --app=plmtcheck worker -l info

Then I see: 
- ** ---------- .> app:         plmtcheck:0x7f9fd2fdf160
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled

I have seen the result is ready.

[2014-05-05 16:16:55,382: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2014-05-05 16:16:55,389: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2014-05-05 16:16:56,401: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2014-05-05 16:16:56,422: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@D-NYC-00552088-Linux ready.
[2014-05-05 16:17:27,726: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: plmtcheck.add[7ea5a501-1085-48b7-8f7e-dac8ac2c5377]
[2014-05-05 16:17:27,759: INFO/MainProcess] Task plmtcheck.add[7ea5a501-1085-48b7-8f7e-dac8ac2c5377] succeeded in 0.032166894000056345s: 37
```

My code is simply

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery('plmtcheck', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://')

@app.task
def add(x, y): 
    return x + y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.worker_main()
```

Comment: It turns out the message is nothing. I can get the result states and result value from client side after I reload the task module

Comment: I am having the disabled trouble too. Works fine on MacOS, however, when I am trying it on a VM it is not working, and the results are disabled.  Not exactly sure what you meant by reload task module

Comment: My results were disabled when reading from the celeryconfig.py. The following worked. app = Celery('tasks', backend='rpc://', broker='amqp://localhost') . The config file reading must have some issue.

Answer (score 0):

install the `django-celery-results` package then add it in settings.py at

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'django_celery_results',
...
]
```

This will do what you intend to do